# Inline array substitution

Tags: bash

I have `file` with a few lines:

```
x 1
y 2
z 3 t
```

I need to pass each line as paramater to some program:

```
$ program "x 1" "y 2" "z 3 t"
```

I know how to do it with **two** commands:

```
$ readarray -t a < file
$ program "${a[@]}"
```

How can i do it with **one** command? Something like that:

```
$ program ??? file ???
```

Comment: If you aren't willing to sacrifice terseness for correctness, you shouldn't be programming in any POSIX-compliant shell language: The long legacy of backwards compatibility means that a lot of default behavior (string-splitting, globbing, etc) is standard-mandated, so one needs to write extra code to force non-default behavior if one cares about correctness.

Comment: ...which is to say, using `readarray` or `mapfile` here is the Right Thing; do you have a *practical* reason to want to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

The (default) options of your `readarray` command indicate that your `file` items are separated by newlines.

So in order to achieve what you want in **one** command, you can take advantage of the special `IFS` variable to use word splitting w.r.t. newlines (see e.g. [this doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html)) and call your `program` with a non-quoted command substitution:

```
IFS=$'\n'; program $(cat file)
```

As suggested by @CharlesDuffy:

1. you may want to disable globbing by running beforehand `set -f`, and if you want to keep these modifications local, you can enclose the whole in a subshell:

   ```
   ( set -f; IFS=$'\n'; program $(cat file) )
   ```
2. to avoid the performance penalty of the parens and of the `/bin/cat` process, you can write instead:

   ```
   ( set -f; IFS=$'\n'; exec program $(<file) )
   ```

   where `$(<file)` is a [Bash equivalent](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution) to to `$(cat file)` (faster as it doesn't require forking `/bin/cat`), and [exec](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-exec) consumes the subshell created by the parens.

   However, note that the `exec` trick won't work and should be removed if `program` is not a real program in the PATH (that is, you'll get `exec: program: not found` if `program` is just a function defined in your script).

Comment: You need to also disable globbing for this to be equivalent.

Comment: And if you don't want the version with the parens to have a performance impact over the version without them, you'll need to end up with something like `(set -f; IFS=$'\n'; exec program $(<file))`  --  the `exec` consumes the subshell created by the parens, and the `$(<...)` form avoids the performance hit of needing to fork off a subprocess in which to exec `/bin/cat`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for your comments, very nice suggestions! (btw it's going to be quite late here so let's say I'll add your suggestions in my answer tomorrow, unless you want to post your own answer to be credited for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Passing a set of params should be more organized :
In this example case I'm looking for a file containing chk_disk_issue=something etc.. so I set the values by reading a config file which I pass in as a param.

```
# -- read specific variables from the config file (if found) --
if [ -f "${file}" ] ;then
    while IFS= read -r line ;do
        if ! [[ $line = *"#"* ]]; then
            var="$(echo $line | cut -d'=' -f1)"
            case "$var" in
                chk_disk_issue)
                    chk_disk_issue="$(echo $line | tr -d '[:space:]' | cut -d'=' -f2 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')"
                ;;
                chk_mem_issue)
                    chk_mem_issue="$(echo $line | tr -d '[:space:]' | cut -d'=' -f2 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')"
                ;;
                chk_cpu_issue)
                    chk_cpu_issue="$(echo $line | tr -d '[:space:]' | cut -d'=' -f2 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')"
                ;;
            esac
        fi
    done < "${file}"
fi
```

if these are not params then find a way for your script to read them as data inside of the script and pass in the file name.